# psychopy - error when trying to set non-scalar variable via conditions file

Tags: python, psychopy

## Summary

In PsychoPy v1.85.1 I am configuring the 'polygon' stimuli object. I am trying to set the height attribute via a csv conditions file. I get an error message saying "Invalid parameter. Single numbers are not accepted"

## Details

PsychoPy v1.85.1 on Windows.

- In the polygon's pop-up UI 'size' box I enter:
  $height
- In the csv-file I have a 'height' column. Each row has values such as:
  (1.5, 0)

PsychoPy gives the error message:

```
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\PsychoPy2\lib\site-packages\psychopy   \visual\basevisual.py", line 1312, in pos
self.__dict__['pos'] = val2array(value, False, False)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\PsychoPy2\lib\site-packages\psychopy\tools\arraytools.py", line 176, in val2array
raise ValueError(msg % str(length))
ValueError: Invalid parameter. Single numbers are not accepted. Should be tuple/list/array of length 2
```

## Troubleshooting - Misc

- Scalar variables work in other csv columns work fine so PsychoPy connects with the csv-file.
- Tried xlsx format.
- Tried entering without parenthesis and with square bracket parenthesis

## Troubleshooting - Running the code outside of PsychoPy

I go to the arraytools.py file and find the relevant code snippet. I paste it into a Python notebook (although it is python 3.3) and add some print rows for debugging:

```
# Copied code snippet from 
# C:\Program Files (x86)\PsychoPy2\lib\site-packages\psychopy\tools\arraytools.py

import numpy

def val2array(value, withNone=True, withScalar=True, length=2):
"""Helper function: converts different input to a numpy array.

    Raises informative error messages if input is invalid.

    withNone: True/False. should 'None' be passed?
    withScalar: True/False. is a scalar an accepted input?
        Will be converted to array of this scalar
    length: False / 2 / 3. Number of elements input should have or be
        converted to. Might be False (do not accept arrays or convert to   such)
"""
    if value is None:
        if withNone:
            return None
        else:
            raise ValueError('Invalid parameter. None is not accepted as '
                         'value.')
    value = numpy.array(value, float)

    print ("value:", value)  #I ADDED
    print ("value.shape:", value.shape)  #I ADDED
    print ("numpy.product(value.shape):", numpy.product(value.shape))  #I ADDED

    if numpy.product(value.shape) == 1: #MY COMMENT: WHY DOES THIS EVALUTE TRUE?
        if withScalar:
            # e.g. 5 becomes array([5.0, 5.0, 5.0]) for length=3
            return numpy.repeat(value, length)
        else:
            msg = ('Invalid parameter. Single numbers are not accepted. '
               'Should be tuple/list/array of length %s')
            raise ValueError(msg % str(length))
    elif value.shape[-1] == length:
        return numpy.array(value, float)
    else:
        msg = 'Invalid parameter. Should be length %s but got length %s.'
        raise ValueError(msg % (str(length), str(len(value))))
```

I test it by entering a value and then run the function.

```
# Run the function
value = (1.5,0.0)
val2array(value, False, False, length =2)
```

Results below. Seems to work fine:

```
value: [ 1.5  0. ]
value.shape: (2,)
numpy.product(value.shape): 2

Out: array([ 1.5,  0. ])
```

### Debugging in Coder View

Thank you Michael. It seems the input value becomes a unicode string which the numpy arrary function cannot convert

```
print "position: ", position
print "type(position): ", type(position)
print "numpy.array(position, float): ", np.array(position, float)

#Results:
position:  (0, 0.5)
type(position):  <type 'unicode'>
numpy.array(position, float): 
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Users\nikla\Documents\PsychoPy\test2.py", line 127, in <module>
print "numpy.array(position, float): ", np.array(position, float)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: (0, 0.5)
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Your first debugging attempt should be to insert `print(height)` and `print(type(height))` in a code component in your Builder file.

Comment: Thank you @MichaelMacAskill. I did that. See above. I also found the fix. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was fixed by entering the attribute values (in the GUI pop-up) using square brackets:

[1.5, 0]

Answer (score 0):

The error has to do with the position attribute rather than the height. Do you set the position to be a scalar? It has to be a coordinate. Try writing the position in your csv file as `(1.5, 0.0)` and then enter `$eval(position)` in Builder (or whatever you called the position column).

Comment: Thanks Jonas. I did have (1.5, 0). Changing to square brackets solved it.